# How to do UI design for all versions of windows mobile in .net

Tags: .net, windows-mobile

I created one UI in windows Mobile 6.5 professional but when i am using  windows Mobile 6.5 240 x 400 the total UI is different from actual design.

can any one say how to design common to all windows mobiles.

Thanks to All.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use scaling factor, based on that u need to judge wat you have to do..

like drawing etc...